# Capture MouseButtons.XButton1/2 for Forward/Backward navigation Windows 10

Tags: c#, mouseevent, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I want to capture the `MouseButtons.XButton` 1 and 2 and enable backward and forward navigation.

In Windows 10 I can capture mouse clicks using

```
this.PointerPressed += LevelsPage_PointerPressed;
private void LevelsPage_PointerPressed(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType == PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
        { 

        }
    }
```

But how do I determine the pointer is `MouseButtons.XButton` or rather `PointerRoutedEventArgs` is of type `MouseEventArgs`? Once determined, I plan to handle the navigation using something like

```
        if (pointer == MouseButton.XButton2 && this.Frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            this.Frame.GoBack();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (pointer == MouseButton.XButton1 && this.Frame.CanGoForward)
        {
            this.Frame.GoForward();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's how I do it

```
    private void LevelsPage_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PointerPoint currentPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(this);
        if (currentPoint.PointerDevice.PointerDeviceType == PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
        {
            PointerPointProperties pointerProperties = currentPoint.Properties;

            if (pointerProperties.IsXButton1Pressed && this.Frame.CanGoBack)
            {
                this.Frame.GoBack();                    
            }
            else if (pointerProperties.IsXButton2Pressed && this.Frame.CanGoForward)
            {
                this.Frame.GoForward();
            }
        }

    }
```